# Why Apache IoTDB reported MaxMessageSize reached, TProtocolException, and frame size has negative value error?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When executing `executeQueryStatement` in Apache IoTDB, these three errors are reported: `executeQueryStatement failed: MaxMessageSize reached`, `executeQueryStatement failed: TProtocolException: Negative size`, `executeQueryStatement failed: Frame size has negative value`. What is the reason for these errors and how should I correct them?